# Json Exception wrong type

Tags: java, json, eclipse, gson

I use Gson in my project. But it returns me error

```
String sig = PortalConfig.getSignature(method, callId, params);
String url = PortalConfig.getUrl(method, callId, sig, params);  
String plainResponse = BaseClientCommunicator.executeGetMethod(url);
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gsonObject = builder.create();
response = gsonObject.fromJson(plainResponse, GetMenuResponse.class);
return response;
```

example I get a Server-response like this

```
{
 "group": 
   [
     {
      "id": "206896",
      "name": "Ryż",
      "info": "xyz"
     },
     {
      "id": "206897",
      "name": "Buraki",
      "info": {}
     }
   ]
}
```

and i have error Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 16151
```

how should I handle this exception??

```
public class GetMenuResponse 
{
@SerializedName("group")
private group[] group;

//method get and set
//to string method
}

public class group
{
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("info")
private String info;

//method get and set
//to string method
}
```

I do not have access to the database, because I use the API

Comment: We'd have to see your `GetMenuResponse` class to be able to find out what exactly went wrong.

Comment: The "info" field of the second item in the array has type object, but the first has type string. Find out why it is being serialized differently on the producing side.

Comment: Your json is not valid  go and check yourself http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Now is correct, this is just an example of my problem and I do not know how to handle this error

Comment: See answer of Yagnesh, and remove '@' before id in @SerializedName("@id") and others.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is at line `"info": {}` in your json string.
Your class have `private String info;` String type and in your JSON string it is JSONObject.
It will try to convert JSONObject into String, which give error `Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT`.`GSON` API cant able to cast JSONObject into JAVA String.

Value of `info` in first element of your array `group` is correct that is `"info": "xyz"` but same variable value in second element is different.
check value of `info` if it is String than you need to check your JSON response coming from server, if not than you need to change it's type into class variable.

Comment: I know that, but how to fix this error ? private ?? info

Comment: @user3405186 first dicide that what is the json response is info is string or it is json object.

Comment: and this is my problem, info is empty object and string :/

Comment: You cant include both, you have to decide either string or object..!!

Comment: Than make sure that value of `info` is always string when you get response from server.

Comment: You have to think some way to identify them OR change logic at which this JSON is generated